# Can SUPEE-1533 be applied after SUPEE-5344 and SUPEE-5994

Tags: security, patches, magento-1.4, ce-1.4.1.1

I have installed the SUPEE-5344 and SUPEE-5994 before, but forgot to install APPSEC-212 and SUPEE-1533. Can these two be installed now? Magento version is 1.4.1.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open the patch scripts to see if there is an intersection of patched files (search for `__PATCHFILE_FOLLOWS__` in the script and check the diff that follows)

#### SUPEE-1533 for Magento 1.4 patches:

- app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
- app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php

#### APPSEC-212 patches:

- app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Wysiwyg/Images.php
- app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php

---

#### SUPEE-5344 for Magento 1.4 patches:

- app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
- app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
- lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php

#### SUPEE-5994 for Magento 1.4 patches:

- app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
- app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php
- app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
- app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
- app/code/core/Mage/Install/Controller/Router/Install.php
- app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/config.xml
- app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/Recurring/ProfileController.php
- lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR.php
- lib/Varien/Io/File.php

As you can see, SUPEE-1533 and APPSEC-212 are independent from SUPEE-5344 and SUPEE-5994, so you can apply them afterwards.

In general, if you try to apply an older patch and it does not find exactly the file that it expects, the whole patch will fail. So you can always try, but look carefully at the output. If it does not say "Patch applied successfully", it did not work.